# I can't get the OSD with omxplayer

Tags: omxplayer, raspbian-buster

I installed omxplayer on Raspbian Buster Lite (no Desktop, no Xserver) on an rpi3.  On my previous builds when I paused a video I would get an OSD with the current runtime and time remaining.  Now nothing appears.  I tried pausing through dBus and terminal.  Neither shows any OSD.

I'm using

`omxplayer --blank "$video"`

to start videos within a screen.

Videos play perfectly fine other than missing OSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use omxplayer wrapped in a script.  When I ran it naked I saw the error message "Error: Unable to open font".  A little search and I found omxplayer uses these fonts for the OSD..

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf

/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansOblique.ttf
```

I downloaded the ttf from the web then..

sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont && chmod 755 freefont
sudo cp /path/to/font/ttf/files /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont
chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/*

then to load them without rebooting..

```
fc-cache
```

I restarted omxplayer and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, install the package containing those fonts:

```
sudo apt install -y fonts-freefont-ttf
```

(Found by searching the [list of font-related packages](https://packages.debian.org/stable/fonts/) on debian.org)

Note: For earlier versions of Raspbian, the package name was different:

```
sudo apt install -y ttf-freefont
```

Comment: Not sure what this did yet, but now omxplayer won't play any videos it once was...

Comment: UPDATE: May have just needed a reboot of the machine.